# Dllimport System.StackOverflowException in WebApp, Console works fine

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, dllimport

I'm pretty stuck and have been searching around for quite a while.
I'm calling a c++ DLL from c#
I can get it all working fine in a simple console app but the identical code does not work in a WebApp

I'm using windows 10 64bit but I've forced everything to use 32bit and calls are Cdecl

c# code:

```
namespace WebApp
{
  public class LibWrap
  {
    [DllImport("mdll.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern Int32 MySize(Int64 start,
      Int32 count,
      Int64[] from,
      Int64[] to,
      Int32[] ids,
      ref Int32 id_cnt);
  }

    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          Int64 l_start = 1431644400;
          Int64[] l_from = {
                                1431644400,
                                1432114200,
                                1432162800,
                                1432278000,
                                1432335600
                            };
          Int64[] l_to = {
                                1431673200,
                                1432119600,
                                1432200600,
                                1432288800,
                                1432364400
                            };
          Int32[] l_IDs = {
                                1,
                                1,
                                1,
                                1,
                                1
                            };
          int l_idCnt = 0;
          Int32 l_Count = LibWrap.MySize(l_start, l_from.Length, l_from, l_to, l_IDs, ref l_idCnt);
        }
    }
}
```

The DLL header code being called is:

```
#define DEF_EXPORT   __declspec(dllexport) __cdecl

int32_t DEF_EXPORT MySize(int64_t   start,
                          int32_t   count,
                          int64_t * from,
                          int64_t * to,
                          int32_t * ids,
                          int32_t & id_cnt);
```

c++ source:

```
int32_t DEF_EXPORT MySize(int64_t   start,
                          int32_t   count,
                          int64_t * from,
                          int64_t * to,
                          int32_t * ids,
                          int32_t & id_cnt)
{
  MyCore mycore;

  int32_t sz = 0;

  if (count)
  {
    mycore.Count = count;

    mycore.Ids    = ids;
    mycore.From   = from;
    mycore.To     = to;

    mycore.Start = start;

    IDList id_positions[MY_LIMIT];
    id_cnt = 1;

    sz = mycore.OutputSize(id_positions, id_cnt);

  }
  return sz;
}
```

As I said WebApp throws a `System.StackOverflowException` error when trying to call `MySize`.
Using debug of native code the `System.StackOverflowException` as soon as I enter the `MySize` function (ie. before the first line is run)
Appreciate any insight, every solution I've found online seems to be already covered in my case.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you stub out the `MySize` method (simply return `0` immediately)?

Comment: @Rob That worth a shot.

Comment: Is there any suspected recursive call in your C++ code?

Comment: I bet the webapp is finding an old dll

Comment: @Rob Thanks for idea, but returning immediately yields the same error.

Comment: @Irshad, no recursion and above immediate return test rules out deeper code in c++

Answer (score 0):

Ok this was an issue of stack memory provided to console apps versus webapps
Under 32bit the web app only get 256Kb.

The culprit is the array:

```
IDList id_positions[MY_LIMIT];
```

Moving this to a dynamic allocation gets it out of the stack and solves the issue.